# Rails Association multiple foreign key same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

I am learning Rails and its Active Records, and I want to set notificatios and send them to a User and register who send it, I have something like this:
Notification Model (I don't know if it is correct to set the ':sender' and ':reciever' like I did):

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
    belongs_to :reciever, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'reciever_id'
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :notifications
end
```

I can do

```
user.notifcations.new(:message => "New notification", :sender => User.first)
```

but when I save (user.save) it shows:

> ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute 'sender_id'

Answer (score 0):

Achieved by adding indexes in the model migration and keeping my models as following:

Migration:

```
class CreateNotifications < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :notifications do |t|
      # Adding index
      t.integer :sender_id

      t.text :message
      t.boolean :seen

      t.boolean :deleted

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :notifications, :sender_id
  end
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :notifications, foreign_key: 'user_id'
    has_many :notifications_sended, class_name: 'Notification', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
end
```

Notification Model:

```
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :reciever, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
    belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
end
```

Also did the AddUserToNotification Migration:

```
rails g migration AddUserToNotification user:references
```

So I can do:

```
User.first.notifications.new(:message => "Hi", :sender => User.second)
```

And:

```
User.first.notifications # Shows the notification
User.second.notifications_sended # Shows the same notification
```